# Как работать с SOAP веб-сервисом из Java?

Tags: java, xml, soap, wsdl

> Достаньте из  http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso?WSDL информацию о коде страны и названии страны и сохраните в Excel файл. Если сможете расширить эту информацию столицей, кодом страны, кодом валюты - только плюс. 
>   Первый запрос должен быть сюда - ListOfContinentsByName, вторая часть информации есть тут - FullCountryInfo"

Год занимаюсь Java, но никогда с подобными вещами дело не имел. Подскажите как это делается... или что гуглить, чтобы понять как и чем это делается на Java?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Поищите в гугле подобное "Парсинг xml java"

Comment: WSDL - это описание сервиса. Сперва нужно сгенерировать по этому описанию код клиента на java, а потом использовать его методы. Как именно это делается, зависит от используемого вами фреймворка. Смотрите, например, [1](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/), [2](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generate-java-code-from-wsdl-or-wadl-dialog.html).

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, было  трудно, но разобрался. Очень помогла статья из коментариев "1" - "Consuming a SOAP web service".  Вот еще хорошые статьи по етому вопросу (кому интересно): [Consume Spring SOAP web services using client application](https://www.javaspringclub.com/consume-spring-soap-web-services-using-client-application-part-ii/), [Обработка ответа SOAP web-сервиса](http://spring-projects.ru/guides/consuming-web-service/). А ето код решения задачи, кому будет интересно - [SpringSoapClient](https://github.com/Misha89ua/SpringSoapClient.git).